# He is the man who I know has helped my son in the final examination

Tags: sentence-construction

> He is the man **who** I know has helped my son in the final examination.

What should be used here who or whom? why?

I know it's a very common mistake, I have also tried to know the rules, still, i make mistakes in it.
Can you suggest me some tricks to get the answer always spot on?

Comment: As a learner: "whom" and "who" both can be used, **but** whom is not common and is used in a very specific context like formal writings. So, I would use "who".

Comment: Have you done any research on this question? A quick search found https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/usage/who-or-whom, which can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

‘who’ should be used in this case because it is referring to the subject of the sentence, which is ‘he’.

Whom should only be used when it is referring to the object of a sentence.

[Visit this website if you have trouble determining the subject and object of sentences.](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/subject-and-object)

[Link to a website discussing the use of who vs whom.](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/who-versus-whom)

One of the tricks I use to determine whether who or whom should be used in a sentence is to rephrase the statement as a question and answer the question myself. If the answer is ‘he’ or ‘she’, ‘who’ should be used. If the answer is ‘him’ or ‘her’, ‘whom’ should be used.

For example, in your case,

**Original**
“He is the man who/whom I know has helped my son in the final examination.”

**Question Form**
“Who/whom helped your son in the final examination?”

**Answer**
“**He** helped my son in the final examination.”

Since the answer to the question uses ‘he’ as the pronoun, ‘who’ is used in the original sentence.

However, the most foolproof way to determine whether to use ‘who’ or ‘whom’ is still to decide whether you are referring to the subject or the object so I highly recommend attempting to perfect that in order to ensure that you are choosing the correct relative pronoun.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is there in another transitive verb know in the sentence which needs an object. This is the teacher whom I know...So should we leave 'know' without any object...

Comment: Your answer may not be clear. Consider editing and adding more detail for clarification.